# How to use list/array comprehension in python to generate cross product pairs

Tags: python, arrays, list

Would it be possible to use list comprehension or array comprehension to generate an array of arrays?

For example, I have a list from 0 to 9:

```
rng = range(0,10)
```

Then I'd like to create a 5-pair cartesion product pairs, from rng above. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
[arr for (for i in range(0,5) arr[i] in rng)]
```

It doesn't compile. Could someone let me know the correct way to code it?

Comment: What's a "5-pair cartesion product pairs"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [4]: list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=2))
Out[4]: 
[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 ...
 (9, 6),
 (9, 7),
 (9, 8),
 (9, 9)]
```

Adjust the `repeat` parameter as required (it sounds like you're looking for `repeat=5`).

If you just need an iterable rather than a list, you can omit the `list()` call.

Answer (score 6):

To do it with a list comprehension:

```
[ (x, y) for x in rangeA for y in rangeB ]
```

I would use `itertools.product`, though, as it is more self-documenting.

After re-reading your question, it also appears you want to compute a cross-product of arbitrary dimension, something that can't be parameterized in a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, would this syntax extend to pairs whose size is specified as input? so that I won't be able to use (x,y,z) etc

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with list comprehension would not be a great way but if you want to do you can do something like this:

```
[(i,j,k,l,m) for i in range(10) for j in range(10) for k in range(10) for l in range(10) for m in range(10)]
```

But I would suggest you to go for `itertools.product()` as @NPE has suggested:

```
list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=5))
```